# Javascript call a function with the handle passed

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function

```
function myFun(myPageErrorCallback){
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',       
    url : someurl,      
    async : true,       
    success : function(data){
                     //display data
              },
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (some condition) {
                  perform default error handling;
            } 
            myPageErrorCallback(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);

    }
});

}
```

At the call,

```
 myPageErrorCallback(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
```

I get a error myPageErrorCallback is not defined.

I tried `myPageErrorCallback.call(...)` but it didnt work

Comment: Then it seems `myPageErrorCallback` is not being passed to `myFun`. Have you checked and confirmed this?

Comment: Ya I have. I have the function call like this `myFun(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){....});`

Comment: How is myFun triggered? link click, button click, form submission.

Comment: @epascarello On button click

Comment: `$("#myButton").on("click",function() {
myFun(
function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){....})
)
}`

Comment: Does this change it: 
`$("#myButton").on( "click", function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); ...  }`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your callback function, or the syntax of how you are passing it into myFun, or the specific error being thrown, it's difficult to know which part of this process is breaking.

Since the error is that your function "myPageErrorCallback" is not defined, we know either nothing is being passed to the myFun function's myPageErrorCallback parameter, or that the what is being passed in is broken.

When you call myFun(), and pass it your call back function, you may be **invoking** that function rather than passing it.

```
myFun(callback()) //invoking
myFun(callback) //passing
```

When you invoke `callback()` as the argument of `myFun()` (instead of passing it), `callback()` is run before `myFun()` and `callback()`'s return value is passed to `myFun()` rather than the function object itself. Using `myFun(callback)` passes the function object itself, rather than the return value of its invocation. To illustrate:

```
function sumNumbers(a,b){
    return a + b;
}

function multiplyNumbers(a,b){
    return a * b;
}

function performCalculation(a, b, calcFunction){
    return calcFunction(a,b);
}

performCalculation(2, 4, sumNumbers); //=> 6

performCalculation(2, 4, multiplyNumbers); //=> 8

performCalculation(2, 4, sumNumbers()) //=> TypeError: number is not a function
```

In the last example, `sumNumbers()` is invoked right away. Its parameters are undefined, so performing `a + b` produces `NaN` (the "not a number" property of the global object). Then, in `performCalculation`, NaN(a,b) is called. javascript (or at least the V8 engine) understands NaN, oddly, as being "numberish", and thus trows the error that "number is not a function".

If you're correctly passing the callback function object, the other possibility is that you haven't defined the function that you're passing in. This can happen if the callback function is not defined before the function that will call back to it, or if your callback function is not defined correctly to begin with.

Comment: No prob @AbhishekAmte, would you mind accepting it as the correct answer? I can always use more rep : )